# Shopware 6.5 update "sticky" dropdown filter selection list in a custom extension

Tags: javascript, shopware, shopware6

My extension worked fine in Showpare 6.4.20. After updating to Shopware 6.5.3, when a checkbox is selected, the filter selection list no longer disappears, when clicking out of the area or another list:

[image]

Subscriber Code:

```
<?php 
class Subscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private EntityRepository $optionRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $optionRepository)
    {
        $this->optionRepository = $optionRepository;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ProductListingCriteriaEvent::class => [
                ['onListingCriteria', -200],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function onListingCriteria(ProductListingCriteriaEvent $event): void
    {
        $event->getCriteria()->addAssociation('properties');
        $event->getCriteria()->addAssociation('properties.group');
        $criteria = $event->getCriteria();
        $filters = $criteria->getExtension('filters');

        //Getting current selected Property Option A to filter out Property Options B
        //..
        $currentPropertyOptions = $propertyFilter->getValues();
        $event->getContext()->addExtension('currentPropertyOptionsCriteria', new ArrayEntity($currentPropertyOptions));

        //getting custom Property Options Tags from administration extension
        $criteria1 = new Criteria();
        $criteria1->addAssociation('myTags');
        $criteria1->setIds($currentPropertyOptions);
        //..
        $tagnames = $tags->map(fn (TagEntity $tag) => $tag->getName());

        $frefixes = ['40f24f88c4c34196ad21ec5dcd094e6a', '813e95deed7047c8bd868e735083be23', '374a5876104a49e88e6aa5a29d85c86b', 'a07ec367574a4c3d81b7fb6ceae66ffe'];

        if (in_array('3f777000a2734deead391133cee3a6a9', $currentPropertyOptions)) {

            $multiFilter = new MultiFilter(MultiFilter::CONNECTION_OR);

            foreach ($tagnames as $tagname) { $multiFilter->addQuery(new PrefixFilter('product.properties.name', $tagname));}

            foreach ($frefixes as $frefix) {
                $multiFilter->addQuery(new EqualsFilter('product.properties.group.id', $frefix));
            }

            $criteria->addFilter($multiFilter);
        }

        if (in_array('87c5e979e6194a8cb3d2625c7b311eeb', $currentPropertyOptions)) {

            $multiFilter = new MultiFilter(MultiFilter::CONNECTION_OR);

            foreach ($tagnames as $tagname) { $multiFilter->addQuery(new PrefixFilter('product.properties.name', $tagname));}

            foreach ($frefixes as $frefix) {
                $multiFilter->addQuery(new EqualsFilter('product.properties.group.id', $frefix));
            }

            $criteria->addFilter($multiFilter);
        }
        //..
    }
}
```

What I have in filter-panel.html.twig:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/component/listing/filter-panel.html.twig' %}

{% block component_filter_panel_items %}

    {% block component_filter_panel_item_properties %}
        {% set properties = listing.aggregations.get('properties') %}
            
            {% for property in properties.entities %}

                {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/component/listing/filter/filter-property-select.html.twig' with {
                    elements: property.options,
                    sidebar: sidebar,
                    name: 'properties',
                    displayName: property.translated.name,
                    displayType: property.displayType,
                    pluginSelector: 'filter-property-select',
                    propertyName: property.translated.name
                } %}

            {% endfor %}

    {% endblock %}
        
{% endblock %}
```

But if I uncheck the checkbox in multiselect dropdown, dropdown disappears as expected (on click behind).

Can someone give a tip on how to debug this Shopware 6.5.3 update issue?

Update to Shopware 6.5.4.1 doesn't help. Looks like ’show’ class should leave, when we click anywhere except the dropdown. But it doesn’t work (when at least one option is checked):

```
<div class="filter-multi-select-dropdown filter-panel-item-dropdown dropdown-menu show" id="filter-properties-1210341102" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px auto auto 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 48px, 0px);" data-popper-placement="bottom-start">
```

No errors in console.

UPDATE:
I was able to get it to work with the following code (for this I installed 'jQuery Support for Shopware >= 6.5'):

```
$("div.dropdown").on("click", function(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on("click", function(event)
{
    $("div.dropdown-menu.show").hide();
});
```

But then the dropdown menu doesn't open, if you click the 'Reset all' filter button, until reloading the page.

Comment: Sticky dropdown dissapears, when the page is manually reloaded. Can someone give a tip to debug this in Shopware 6.5?